# How to pervent JPanel keep duplicate the lasted clicked J Components Object into its panel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paintcomponent

I'm doing my final project for my college. And I don't have much Java knowledge to debug the code. The bug is in question. I am to drop 3 classes Java code here, Drawing Panel, the Jframe and main() one.

main() code:

```
package test;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
          Aaa a = new Aaa();
    }
}
```

Aaa code (IDK what to name):

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Aaa extends JFrame{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel text = new JLabel("please try click on the button first, then drawing, then click and draw again.");
    JButton button = new JButton("bug here");
    DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
    
    public Aaa() {
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(button);
        this.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        this.setSize(700,500);
        this.setTitle("Submit to StackOverFlow");
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

DrawingPanel() Class (Personally suspect this is where the bug is. I have been using this in different projects and it got the same bug too):

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
    boolean mouse = false;
    private int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    protected int resetCount = 0;
    
    public DrawingPanel() {
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (mouse) {
            if (resetCount == 0 ) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                resetCount++;
            }
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }
     
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouse = false;
    }
    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mouse= true;
        x2 = (int) e.getPoint().getX();
        y2 = (int) e.getPoint().getY();
    }
    
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
        x2 = (int) e.getPoint().getX();
        y2 = (int) e.getPoint().getY();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

With these 3 codes run together, DrawingPanel drawingPanel will copy JButton button onto the top left of its panel. If there's 2 or more button it will copy the lasted one. the 1st clicked button will not be duplicate onto its panel. Sometimes this bug applies to JTextField too. Also, we can paint over the panel! This is the picture of
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD1Fz.png)

If anyone knows how to debug this I'm all ears to fix them, Thank you so much!

Comment: Painting is destructive.  When `paintComponent` is called, you're expected to repaint the entire component state as required.  This means you need to maintain some kind of model/state of what you want to paint.

Comment: I used paintComponent because it was one of the requirements for my final. Is it mean as long as I use this method it'll duplicate the buttons? So I have to focus on cover them right?

Comment: So long as you misuse this method, it will produce a duplicate button - always call `super.paintComponent`

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer! However, I tried called super.paintComponent() and super.repaint() replacing two of them respectively and the bug is still there. When I replace super.repaint() with super.paintComponent(), the button replica is gone but I can't draw lines in the panel.

Comment: *but I can't draw lines in the panel* - see [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two commons ways to do incremental painting.